# How to configure path to a file in resource folder in git?

Tags: json, git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to Jenkins. I am building a project on eclipse with a `Jenkinsfile` written in groovy script.  The script reads a json file in the resource folder in the project.  I commit the project to github and have configured jenkins to do a build job using the Jenkinsfile.  I am getting a `filenotfound` exception.  In my code I initially used Resources/abc.json as a url but then used https://github.com/test/jsonFilepraser/tree/master/Resources/abc.json  but in both cases the error is the same.  Any help with the path that I should use will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort the problem.  In my code where I was defining a file object that had in the argument the json file, I was not using "" and therefore it was throwing an error.  I also moved the JSON file out of the folder and didn't use the folder extension to locate the file and it solved all the problem.